# Oddness with task filters in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

My work outlook account has multiple datafiles in it.  One of them is shared with other people, and I want to exclude it from my task list view

I use the task list to manage follow ups on emails.  I want to list of tasks generated from the follow up flags to only display tasks from my primary datafile.

By default, it is only displaying uncompleted tasks from all datafiles.

If I add in a rule to only display from one of my datafiles, this works, BUT the filtering on completed tasks stops working meaning I see all my completed tasks included with the

Here is the rule generated that doesn't seem to work!

("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/81010003" <> 2 AND "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:outlook#source-table-label" LIKE '%outlook0.pst%')

Any ideas?

Comment: we can hide flagged items of other mailbox in To-Do Bar: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/de0dd7a5-1b98-40c8-a56b-b38d16984d8d/multiple-exchange-accounts-cannot-filter-todo-list-for-flagged-emails?forum=outlook

Comment: Oooh.  That might work.  I'll try

Comment: How did you share data file with other people?

Comment: @Perry Worked!  Thank you!

Comment: @thims Its just another exchange account added in the email accounts settings that multiple people also use.